# Populate QComboBox with a list

Tags: python, pyqt, qstring

I'm developing a GUI dialog using PyQT4 which imports some data into a Pandas DataFrame and then plots the data to an embedded Matplotlib canvas.

I'd like to pass a list of variable from the DataFrame to the combo box. My first attempt was:

```
list = list(df.parameter,unique())
self.FirstComboBox = QtGui.QComboBox()
self.FirstComboBox.addItems(list)
```

But on running this I get

```
TypeError: QComboBox.addItems(QStringList): argument 1 has unexpected type 'list'
```

I've seen examples where a sorted list of dict keys is passed to a combo box, so I'm confused that I can't pass a list.

Ben

Answer (score 3):

In the end I got this to work. But I'm not happy with it.

```
        for i in range(len(channels)):
            self.MyComboBox.addItem(channels[i])
```

Comment: In Python, this sort of explicit iteration trivially reduces to: `for channel in channels: self.MyComboBox.addItem(channel)`. PySide2 sadly appears to require similar circumvention. In particular,  the `"TypeError: 'PySide2.QtWidgets.QComboBox.addItems' called with wrong argument types"` exception is raised on attempting to pass a pure-Python sequence of strings to *any* `addItems()` method – a blatant failure of the underlying binding generator (e.g., SIP, Shiboken2). `</ugh>`

Comment: **Oh, I see.** In my case, I was attempting to pass a view of `OrderedDict` values (i.e., the sequence returned by the `OrderedDict.values()` method) to the `QComboBox.addItems()` method. Since this view *is* a valid sequence, this should technically work. It doesn't, because the binding generator appears to only support `tuple` and `list` sequences. In my case, the solution was thus to coerce the desired sequence into a `tuple` first: e.g., `self.MyComboBox.addItems(tuple(channels))`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're using the old v1 api.  You can use the [newer api](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/incompatible_apis.html), which removes the need for casting strings to `QStrings` (or `QStringLists` in this case).

```
import sip
# Do this before you import PyQt
sip.setapi('QString', 2)

from PyQt4 import QtCore
```

Answer (score 0):

The addItems works for this

```
months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar']
cbo = QComboBox()
cbo.addItems(months)
```